# How to get Vertical navigation in recent apps on my Pixel 6

Tags: google-pixel-6

This question has already been asked several times in 2018 and 2020, but all the answers are outdated.

I want my vertically scrolling recent apps switcher back. It is so much better than the native horizontal switching: you can see 5 apps at the time and it scrolls smoothly; if the app is a bit further away switching can be literally 10x as fast.

I can't get it to work with Nova Launcher, and the Good Lock solution is only for Galaxy phones.

Who can help me?